# Placement of interfaces in visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, interface

What is best practise with regard to the placement of *Interface* types.

Often the quickest and easiest thing to do is place the interface in the same project as the concrete instances of it - however, if I understand things correctly this means that you are more likely to end-up with project dependency issues. Is this a fair assessment of the situation and if so does this mean interfaces should be separated out into different projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. You're correct that placing interfaces and classes in the same assembly will somewhat limit the usefulness of the abstraction of said interfaces. E.g. if you want to load types in an AppDomain with the purpose of unloading these again, you would typically access instances via the interfaces. However, if interfaces and classes are in the same assembly you can't load the interfaces without loading the classes as well.

Similarly if you at a later point want to supply a different set of classes for one or more interfaces you will still get all the old types if they are in the same assembly as the interfaces.

With that said I must admit that I do place interfaces and classes in the same assembly from time to time simply because I don't think that I will need the flexibility, so I prefer to keep things simple. As long as you have the option to rebuild everything you can rearrange the interfaces later if the need arises.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple solution, I might have public interfaces and public factory classes, and internal implementation classes all in the same project.

In a more complicated solution, then to avoid a situation where project A depends on the interfaces in project B, and project B depends on the interfaces defined in project A, I might move the interfaces into a separate project which itself depends on nothing and which all other projects can depend on.

I practice "big systems can't be created from scratch: big systems which work are invariable found to have evolved from small systems which worked." So I might well start with a small and simple solution with the interfaces in the same project as the implementation, and then later (if and when it's found to be necessary) refactor that to move the interfaces into a separate assembly.

Then again there's packaging; you might develop separate projects, and repackage everything into a single assembly when you ship it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a deployment detail.  There are a few cases where you *have* to put an interface type in its own assembly.  Definitely when using them in plug-in development or any other kind of code that runs in multiple AppDomains.  Almost definitely when Remoting or any other kind of connected architecture.

Beyond that, it doesn't matter so much anymore.  An interface type is just like another class, you can add an assembly reference if you need it in another project.  Keeping them separate can help controlling versioning.  It is a good idea to keep them separate if a change in an interface type can lead to wide-spread changes in the classes that implement them.  The act of changing the [AssemblyVersion] when you do so now helps troubleshooting deployment issues where you forgot to update a client assembly.